# How do you login into /bin/bash automatically?

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, rails, rvm

Im on 12.04 LTS and am doing to Ruby on Rails development. When I start up my terminal and type in `ruby -v` it will list my Ruby as 1.8.7. When I type in `/bin/bash --login` then `ruby -v` will list it as 2.0.0 which is what I want in order to run rails 4.0. Problem is that I have to type in `/bin/bash --login` everytime I start up my terminal. Is there a way that I can log into `/bin/bash` automatically when I open up my terminal?

Comment: Could you run `echo $PATH; which ruby` once before and once after running `bash` and show the output here?

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: This is the before : /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ordep/.rvm/bin
/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: This is the after: /home/ordep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/ordep/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/home/ordep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/home/ordep/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
/home/ordep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby

Comment: Did you add something to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` when installing this ruby thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open the terminal
- From menu-bar, select Edit > Profiles
- In opened prompt Edit > Default
- In Tab "Title & Commands" -> check "Run Command as Login Shell"
- Restart Terminal

Now you need not to run /bin/bash --login again .

Answer (score 1):

Technically, RVM is loaded into your shell session as a function. If you're using Bash as your shell, this integration is done by the config file `.bash_profile`. As you might know, there are different "types" of shell sessions, namely *login* shells, *interactive* shells and *non-interactive* shells. Depending on which of that your bash session is, different config files get involved. The `.bash_profile` config file, that handles the integration of RVM, is included with login shell sessions, but not with "merely" interactive or non-interactive shell sessions. For more details, you can read up [in the RVM docs](http://rvm.io/support/faq#what-shell-login-means-bash-l).

So you need to make sure that when you start up your terminal, the shell session is started as a login shell session. There probably is a setting with your terminal emulator for this. With the command `/bin/bash --login` that you used so far, you do nothing other than start *another* shell session inside your shell session, but this one as a login shell.

You probably have installed Ruby by the package manager (`apt-get`) in addition to installing it via RVM. So when RVM isn't integrated to your shell session, you're left with the "system Ruby". That's why you kind of "fall back" to Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I'm using the default ubuntu terminal. How do I go about getting it to start in login shell?

Comment: Terminal->Edit->Profiles->Default->Edit->Title and Command->Run command as login shell. But a more elegant approach would be to fix the initialization so that ruby is properly configured on any shell.

Comment: I must ask how would go about fixing the initialization? Im a complete Linux noob.

Comment: I'd recommend against "fixing" the initialization, because RVMs upgrade process only takes care of login shells. If you add your own initialization for non-login shells, you would have to maintain that yourself manually. If you want to do that, you can look for the line that the RVM install added to your `~/.bash_profile` (should be the only line with respect to RVM) and copy it to `~/.profile`. But in my opinion, just setting your terminal to start a login shell would be the preferred option. Almost all other terminal emulators do so by default, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Solution which works for me is to add following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```